# How many join to pivot does it need to get different tags?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've joined to a project recently. I'm reviewing codes and I've faced with this query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN pivot pi1 on p.id = pi1.post_id
INNER JOIN tags t1 on t1.id = pi1.tag_id and t1.name = "mysql"
INNER JOIN pivot pi2 on p.id = pi2.post_id
INNER JOIN tags t2 on t2.id = pi2.tag_id and t2.name = "php"
```

It selects all posts which are tagged with both `mysql` and `php` tags. My question is about the joins. Why joining to the `pivot` table twice? Why not joining to `pivot` once and use it for tags twice?

Comment: Because a single row in the `pivot` table cannot match two different tags.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* join to the pivot table once, if you want to use aggregation:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN pivot pi 
     ON p.id = pi.post_id
INNER JOIN tags t
     ON t.id = pi.tag_id AND t.name IN ('mysql', 'php')
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

In your version, one row in `pivot` cannot match both values.  So, you need two joins.

Comment: Ok, let me ask you one question, is the order of joins (under each other) important?

Comment: @stack No, they shouldn't be, because you'd only retain a post which survived both inner joins.  The order in which you filter for each tag does not matter in the end.

Comment: Ok, I will go with your version. Just I need to know what does `COUNT(*)` point to? What happens if we just want to select posts? (there is no tags filtering anymore). Should it be equal to `COUNT(*) = 0` in that case?

Comment: @stack count(*) give you no. of tags per post so in case of post with tags mysql and php count(*) should be 2 and for case posts with no tags it should be count(*) = 0

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I see, I'm just interested to know, how `COUNT(*)` counts the number of post's tags? Why it doesn't count the number of selected posts?

Comment: @stack because you are grouping results by `p.id` means products.id, if you want to count posts per tags then selection would be t.* and group by on tag.id

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I understand what you said and you are right (based on some tests). But still I don't understand the syntax. `p.id` groups posts per their ids. Also id is an unique thing and then `COUNT(*)` should be the number of posts. Why it isn't?! Who knows!